# Exception is thrown when file saving is performed

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I trying to save (File > Save) my ERD diagram within Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeller (Version 17.3.0.261) .dmd file but when saving is performed exception is thrown:

```
2020-10-25 12:57:08,353 [Thread-85] ERROR XMLTransformationManager - Can not write document to file: /private/var/folders/zr/x6pt52n96pj59fcrfpyqk__m0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/01746F71-9829-4974-9624-E9464A2E0B4F/d/OracleDataModeler-17.3.0.261.1529.app/Contents/Resources/datamodeler/datamodeler/types/defaultdomains.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/folders/zr/x6pt52n96pj59fcrfpyqk__m0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/01746F71-9829-4974-9624-E9464A2E0B4F/d/OracleDataModeler-17.3.0.261.1529.app/Contents/Resources/datamodeler/datamodeler/types/defaultdomains.xml (Read-only file system)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.model.metadata.XMLTransformationManager.saveDocument(XMLTransformationManager.java:3899)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.model.metadata.XMLTransformationManager.saveDefaultDomain(XMLTransformationManager.java:4300)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.model.metadata.XMLTransformationManager.saveDomains(XMLTransformationManager.java:4248)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.model.metadata.XMLTransformationManager.saveDesign(XMLTransformationManager.java:301)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.model.design.Design.saveAll(Design.java:2147)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.swingui.ControllerApplication.saveAll(ControllerApplication.java:4025)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.swingui.ControllerApplication.saveAsDesign(ControllerApplication.java:3815)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.swingui.ControllerApplication.access$6200(ControllerApplication.java:121)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.swingui.ControllerApplication$SaveAs$1.run(ControllerApplication.java:3681)
```

What have I do and what extra details have I provide here? My OS is Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder you are saving to, is read only

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /private/var/folders/zr/x6pt52n96pj59fcrfpyqk__m0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/01746F71-9829-4974-9624-E9464A2E0B4F/d/OracleDataModeler-17.3.0.261.1529.app/Contents/Resources/datamodeler/datamodeler/types/defaultdomains.xml
> (Read-only file system)

Just move the SQL dev Data modeler to another folder on which you can write (desktop for instance), or just "*Save As*" at another place.

Comment: Another exception is thrown now - 2020-10-27 12:24:38,115 [Thread-47] ERROR XMLTransformationManager - Can not write document to file: /task_2/pm/Process Model.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /task_2/pm/Process Model.xml (No such file or directory). What's going on? I obtain this error each time I try save today.